# Install command line application on android globally using termux `apt`

Tags: root-access

I love Termux, It feels like i using Linux on my phone. Sometimes I use my phone on my pc via ssh-helper but sadly I can't use any Termux app installed via `apt` command. Is there any way to install apps globally using `apt install`. I aleady rooted my android phone.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for SSH access to Termux you can install sshd with `apt install openssh`.

Setup the authorized keys as normal (`$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`), start the `sshd` daemon and connect on port 8022 by default.

Comment: To expand on @fornwall answer, I believe you HAVE to connect to the SSHD provided by Termux to access the Termux environment, since Termux is running in its own container. other SSH servers will not be able to connect to that environment directly. If you have root, you can navigate from Termux-connected ssh to other locations on the filesystem.